# Python - Pandas: get row indices for a particular value in a column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a pandas dataframe, is there a way to get the indices of rows where a column has particular values?

Consider the following toy example:

**CSV** (*save as test1.csv*)

```csv
id,val1,val2
1,20,A
1,19,A
1,23,B
2,10,B
2,10,A
2,14,A
```

What I currently have is this:

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('test1.csv')
print(df)

print(df[df['id']==1].index.to_list())
print(df[df['id']==2].index.to_list())
```

```bash
   id  val1 val2
0   1    20    A
1   1    19    A
2   1    23    B
3   2    10    B
4   2    10    A
5   2    14    A
[0, 1, 2]
[3, 4, 5]
```

Is there an option/functionality that can give me something like the following?
(I want to be able to do this for large value lists, **fast**!)

```py
print(df['id'].someFn([1,2]))
```

Desired output:

```bash
{1:[0,1,2], 2:[3,4,5]}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `groupby`:

```
{k: list(d.index) for k, d in df.groupby('id')}
```

Output:

```
{1: [0, 1, 2], 2: [3, 4, 5]}
```